# Método que devuelve String y recibe LocalTime

Tags: java, string, localtime

Tengo un método que recibe un objeto LocalTime , y que devuelve un String , el objetivo de este método es que al recibir una hora sea por ejemplo --> 13:00 devuelva("Son las 13 en punto") , otro ejemplo sería --> 17:08("Son las 17 y 8").
¿Por dónde debería empezar?¿Pasando el objeto LocalTime a String?

EDITO creo que ya he conseguido la respuesta , la pongo por si alguien quiere saberlo.Basándome en las respuestas de los compañeros a esta pregunta.

```
private static String generaTextoHora(LocalTime tiempo){

    Integer hora = tiempo.getHour();
    Integer minutos = tiempo.getMinute();
    String mensaje = "";
    if(minutos==00){
        mensaje = "son las " + hora + " en punto";
    }else if(minutos>0 && minutos <15){
        mensaje = "son las " + hora + " y " + minutos;
    }else if(minutos==15){
        mensaje = "son las " + hora +" y cuarto";
    }else if(minutos>15 && minutos>30){
        mensaje = "son las " + hora + " y " + minutos;
    }else if(minutos==30){
        mensaje = "son las" + hora + " y media";
    }else if(minutos>30 && minutos<=59){
        mensaje = "son las" + hora + " y " + minutos;
    }
    return mensaje;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el metodo toString() que te lo convertirá a un string como:
- "HH:MM"
- "HH:MM:SS"
- ...
- "HH:MM:SS.999999999"

Despues puedes separar con un split(":");

```
public string mensajeHora(LocalTime tiempo){

    String[] mensaje = tiempo.toString().split(":");
    String hora  = mensaje[0];
    String minutos = mensaje[1];
    String mensajeTexto = "";

    if(minutos == "00"){

        mensajeTexto = "Son las " + hora + " en punto");
    }else{
        mensajeTexto = "Son las " + hora + " y "+ minutos);

    }

    return mensajeTexto;

}
```

Comment: Pero cogiendo el mensaje[1] , ya consigo lo que hay a la derecha del método split ":" ? Osea , los minutos

Comment: split te lo divide por el caracter ":". si tenias HH:MM tendras un array de 2 elementos, asi que accediendo al segundo coges minutos. con HH:MM:SS tienes 3 elementos y accedes al tecero para segundos

Comment: Por cierto tu codigo no me compila lois6b , devuelves un array de string , no un string

Comment: Me estaba equivocando yo , si vale. Muchas gracias

Comment: En el caso de que no tenga Formato HH:MM debería formatearlo con un DataTimeFormatter?

Comment: no hace falta formatear. puede tener hasta segundos con 9 digitos de precision pero mientras accedas a los dos primeros elementos del array tras split, siempre seran horas y minutos. Abarca todos los formatos posibles

Comment: Para abstraerte de formatos, acude directamente a `getHour()` y `getMinute()`

Comment: Corrijo , el método no vale porque es un array mensajes , y devuelves un array mensajes también , cuando se debería devolver un String

Comment: @DioniGálvezCamacho, Editado

Answer (score 4):

Como siempre, acude a la documentación de la clase que quieras usar.

[LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)

Allí podrás ver métodos como `getHour()`, `getMinute()`, o `getSecond()`

Luego podrás devolver un String basado en esos campos. Algo como:

```
public String getLocalTimeMessage(LocalTime localTime) {
    int hour = localTime.getHour();
    int minute = localTime.getMinute();

    String message = "Son las ";
    message += hour;

    if (minute == 0) {
        message += " en punto";
    } else {
        message += " y " + minute;
    }

    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Un String nunca se debería igualar utilizando ==  ya que es un objeto se debería utilizar .equals() para comparar. @lois6b

Comment: equalsIgnoreToCase , debería?

Comment: En este caso no porque estas comparando números si fuesen una cadena con mayúsculas y minúsculas y aquello contra que lo quieres comparar fuese todo minúsculas, en ese caso si te sería útil.